STM32G0B0 writing to PD1 affects PD0
Note: Cross-posted to ST-Community Forum
I am running into an issue with the STM32G0B0 MCU:
Writing to PD1 seems to result in the opposite value being somehow applied to PD0, even though PD0 is set to input.
Effectively, I created a new project in STM32CubeIDE, configured PD0 & PD2 as GPIO_Input (with pullup enabled) and PD1 as GPIO_Output.
Next, I added the following code to the main function:
 /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
      {
      }

      GPIOD->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_1;


      for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
      {
      }

      GPIOD->BRR = GPIO_PIN_1;
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

Running this code on the MCU (the board is effectively empty: There are some bypass caps next to the power pins & two pullup on a couple of other, unrelated pins) results in the following output on the two pins:

PD2 is DIO5, PD1 is DIO6, PD0 is DIO7. I have reproduced this behavior on 4 different boards by now.
What is going on here? Why is the input pin being affected by the output pin? How can I fix this?

What board are you using? Are the signals somehow connected?

Does your logic analyzer have a good ground connection to your board?  Have you perhaps redefined GPIO_PIN_1 somewhere?  Looks like a value of 0x10002 (instead of the correct 0x0002) would cause your code to toggle the two pins just as you describe, although this would require that PD0 is actually misconfigured as an output.

@jib The board is a custom one, with simple traces going to a bunch of header pins for easy debugging. Turns out it was a configuration issue related to the UCPD1/UCPD2 bits, see my answer below. (Although I don't understand exactly how that setting leads to the observed behavior...)

@jasonharper no macros were redefined - see also my reply to Jib above

Solved by @TDK in the linked ST-Community thread:
It appears as though there are some special-function pull-downs on those particular pins, which can be disabled by writing to SYSCFG->CFGR1, in particular the UCPD1 and UCPD2 bits. Adding the following line fixed the issue:
HAL_SYSCFG_StrobeDBattpinsConfig(SYSCFG_UCPD1_STROBE | SYSCFG_UCPD2_STROBE);

